# Spresenseの拡張カードに実装されているアンプICについて

Tags: spresense

Spresense用のヘッドフォン用出力基板を自作しようとしているのですが

Spresense用拡張カードに実装されているオーディオヘッドフォンアンプIC（NJU72040V(TE2)）が
購入できず困っています。
メーカーに確認しても、1リール(2000個)での購入になってしまいます。

代替となるアンプICがあれば教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: JRC は他が作らないようなニッチICのメーカーなうえにこのチップって新製品ぢゃん。完全互換なものって探しても簡単には見つからない気がします。何個必要なんですか？

Comment: 互換品はなさそうですね。使い慣れているアンプICをお使いになるのがよいかと。JRCと同じコンデンサ不要なものであれば、TIのTPA6130A2がマウザーやRSにあるようです。国産がよければロームのBD88200GULがマウザーにありました。ご参考まで。